# Convert a Dictionary to string of url parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, webforms

Is there a way to convert a Dictionary in code into a url parameter string?

e.g.

```
// An example list of parameters
Dictionary<string, object> parameters ...;
foreach (Item in List)
{
    parameters.Add(Item.Name, Item.Value);
}

string url = "http://www.somesite.com?" + parameters.XX.ToString();
```

Inside MVC HtmlHelpers you can generate URLs with the UrlHelper (or Url in controllers) but in Web Forms code-behind the this HtmlHelper is not available.

```
string url = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl("Default", "Action", "Controller", 
    new RouteValueDictionary(parameters), htmlHelper.RouteCollection , 
    htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, true);
```

How could this be done in C# Web Forms code-behind (in an MVC/Web Forms app) without the MVC helper?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

One approach would be:

```cs
var url = string.Format("http://www.yoursite.com?{0}",
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string.Join("&",
        parameters.Select(kvp =>
            string.Format("{0}={1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value)))));
```

You could also use string interpolation as introduced in C#6:

```cs
var url = $"http://www.yoursite.com?{HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string.Join("&", parameters.Select(kvp => $"{kvp.Key}={kvp.Value}")))}";
```

And you could get rid of the `UrlEncode` if you don't need it, I just added it for completeness.

Comment: Not such efficient: `string.Format` repeated (params.Count + 1) times, creating IEnumerator<T> object, so many methods are invoked. Creating anonymous method. So much work to simply concatenate strings (.

Comment: If you do not put the http://www.yoursite.com? part outside the UrlEncode, the result will look like this: http%3a%2f%2fwww.yoursite.com%3f ...  I would do the encoding on the key and value and nothing else. Something like this: $"http ://www.yoursite.com?{string.Join("&", parameters.Select(kvp => $"{HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key)}={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value)}"))}"

Comment: This is invalid answer. `HttpUtility.UrlEncode("a=b&c=d")` will encode '=' and '&' characters and return `"a%3db%26c%3dd"`.
Correct method: `$"https://example.com?{string.Join("&", parameters.Select(kvp => $"{HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key)}={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value)}"))}"`

Comment: I think there is no need to url encode the dictionary Key. I instead just url encode the Value. This safely works for me: string.Join("&", parameters.Select(kvp => $"{kvp.Key}={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value)}"))

Comment: This does not work properly, it encodes also "=" and "&" characters

Answer (score 34):

You can use QueryHelpers from Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities:

```
string url = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString("https://me.com/xxx.js", dictionary);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (at least as of .NET Core 3.1+). `AddQueryString` has an overload that takes a Dictionary that lets you append query keys/values to an existing string URL - perfect.

Comment: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities` has been deprecated

Answer (score 15):

Make a static helper class perhaps:

```
public static string QueryString(IDictionary<string, object> dict)
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    foreach(var item in dict)
    {
        list.Add(item.Key + "=" + item.Value);
    }
    return string.Join("&", list);
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I'm not saying this option is better (I personally think it's not), but I'm here just to say it exists.

The [`QueryBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions.querybuilder?view=aspnetcore-3.1) class:

```cs
var queryStringDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "username", "foo" },
    { "password", "bar" }
};

var queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder(queryStringDictionary);
queryBuilder.Add("type", "user");

//?username=foo&password=bar&type=user
QueryString result = queryBuilder.ToQueryString();
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not the better option? I think it's better because you don't have to encode the values yourself. It's a much smaller solution.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a `IEnumerable<string>` and [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var parameters = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in List)
{
    parameters.Add(item.Name + "=" + item.Value.ToString());
}

string url = "http://www.somesite.com?" + String.Join("&", parameters);
```

or shorter

```
string baseUri = "http://www.somesite.com?";
string url = baseUri + String.Join("&", list.Select(i => $"{i.Name}={i.Value}"));
```

Comment: I'm clearly missing something, because it looks like if you pass in `{ "abc" -> "def", "ghi" -> "jkl" }` this produces `abc=&def&ghi=&jkl`.

Answer (score 5):

the most short way:

```
string s = string.Join("&", dd.Select((x) => x.Key + "=" + x.Value.ToString()));
```

But shorter does not mean more efficiency. Better use `StringBuilder` and `Append` method:

```
first = true;
foreach(var item in dd)
{
    if (first)
        first = false;
    else
        sb.Append('&');
    sb.Append(item.Key);
    sb.Append('=');
    sb.Append(item.Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: As always, it depends.
http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/stringbuilder.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46151516/is-it-true-that-stringbuilder-is-slower-than-concatenate-a-dozen-of-strings

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> // this is wrong
> var url = string.Format("http://www.yoursite.com?{0}",
>     HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string.Join("&",
>         parameters.Select(kvp =>
>             string.Format("{0}={1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value)))));
> ```

I tried this code from the accepted answer (of Mike), but it did not worked. Actually that is wrong. Let's see what is wrong with that answer.
If you write `HttpUtility.UrlEncode("a=1&b=2")`, it will also encode `=` and `&` and returns `"a%3d1%26b%3d2"` which is not correct. So, you need to encode just keys and values like this:

```cs
// this works
var encodedUrl = string.Format("http://www.yoursite.com?{0}", 
    string.Join("&", parameters.Select(kvp => string.Format("{0}={1}", 
        HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value)))));
```

Or (using string interpolation)

```cs
var encodedUrl = $"http://www.yoursite.com?{string.Join("&", parameters.Select(kvp => $"{HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key)}={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value)}"))}";
```

Answer (score 2):

I have written these extensions methods:

**Add querystring to base url:**

```
public static string AddQueryString(this string url, IDictionary<string, object> parameters) => 
     $"{url}?{parameters.ToQueryString()}";
```

**Convert dictionary of parameters to query string:**

```
private static string ToQueryString(this IDictionary<string, object> parameters) => 
    string.Join("&", parameters.Select(x => $"{x.Key}={x.Value}"));
```

*Actual code to convert to query string:*

```
string.Join("&", parameters.Select(x => $"{x.Key}={x.Value}"));
```

Edit:

When using in production consider encoding the parameters with `URL.Encode` within this function. If you use this make sure the parameters in the dictionary are not already encoded.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz implementation detail

Comment: Yes, **correct** implementation detail. Otherwise It could lead to bugs

Comment: Agree with Carlos: `string.Join("&", parameters.Select(kvp => $"{WebUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key)}={WebUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value.ToString())}"));`

Comment: @Thymine I added a comment. In my scenario, the parameters are already encoded within the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you looking for (untested code)?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("http://www.somesite.com?");

foreach(var item in parameters)
{
sb.append(string.Format("{0}={1}&", item.Key, item.Value))
}
string finalUrl = sb.ToString();
finalUrl = finalUrl.Remove(finalUrl.LasIndexOf("&"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>(); // You pass this
var url = "http://www.somesite.com?";
int i = 0;
foreach (var item in parameters)
{
    url += item.Key + "=" + item.Value;
    url += i != parameters.Count ? "&" : string.Empty;
    i++;
}

return url;
```

I have not run the logic, but this might help you.

If you would be UrlRouting in webforms then it would be a different story.

Check out:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using Newtonsoft JSON you can can quickly serialize an anonymous object into a http query by making extension functions.

This method also supports passing arrays as parameters to PHP using brackets.

```
    public static string Join(this List<string> a, string seperator)
    {
        return string.Join(seperator, a.ToArray());
    }

    public static string ToHttpQuery(this object a)
    {
        string result = "";

        foreach (var b in JObject.FromObject(a))
        {
            if (result.Length > 0)
                result += "&";

            if (b.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
                result += b.Value.Select(x => b.Key + "[]=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(x.ToString())).ToList().Join("&");
            else
                result += b.Key + "=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(b.Value.ToString());
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Example usage:

```
        string query = new
        {
            test = new string[] { "ree", "roo" },
            myId = 123,
            port = PORTS.MAIN_INTERFACE_IO,
            targetUrl = "http://example.com/?fee=123"
        }.ToHttpQuery();
        
        string myUrl = "http://example.com/?" + query;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old also there are other correct answers.

However, the builtin `HttpValueCollection` already does escaping correctly, the only trick then is to rewrite the dictionary to it.

This means the following snippet reuses the implementation from the base class library and would be useful for anyone not using the NET.Core implementations (for example - people who still code against NET.Framework)

```
public static string ToQueryString( IDictionary<string, object> dict )
{
    var collection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

    foreach ( var key in dict.Keys )
    {
        collection.Add( key, dict[key].ToString() );
    }

    return collection.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add the following class to the project and use the extension method.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public static class CollectionExtensions {
    public static string ToQueryString(this IDictionary<string, string> dict)
    {

    if (dict.Count == 0) return string.Empty;

    var buffer = new StringBuilder();
    int count = 0;
    bool end = false;

    foreach (var key in dict.Keys)
    {
        if (count == dict.Count - 1) end = true;

        if (end)
            buffer.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", key, dict[key]);
        else
            buffer.AppendFormat("{0}={1}&", key, dict[key]);

        count++;
    }

    return buffer.ToString();
}
}
```

to use the code:

```
var queryString = dictionary.ToQueryString();
```