# Is it true that StringBuilder is slower than concatenate a dozen of strings?

Tags: c#, .net, string, stringbuilder

Is it true that StringBuilder is slower than concatenate a dozen of strings?
How does compiler optimize the string concatenation so that joining a dozen of strings using "+" will be better than StringBuilder?

From a book (written by Ben Watson) it says that:

> String Concatenation: For simple concatenation of a known (at compile
>   time) quantity of strings, just use the ‘+’ operator or the
>   String.Concat method. This is usually more efficient than using a
>   StringBuilder.    string result = a + b + c + d + e + f;    Do not
>   consider StringBuilder until the number of strings is variable and
>   likely larger than a few dozen. The compiler will optimize simple
>   string concatenation in a way to lessen the memory overhead.

Comment: [Race your horses...](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Write for clarity. If you have performance goals, write clear code then *measure* it against those goals. If it meets them, great. If it doesn't, look at ways to re-write the actual hot-spots in your code. Don't assume you can learn a billion small "performance" rules that you can then blindly apply to all code writing and achieve good performance.

Comment: @JonSkeet ah, I hadn't spotted I was in the `string` tag, rather than `java`.

Comment: On the other hand, if certain patterns tend to be more efficient than others, why not use them to start off with (assuming they're equally clear)?

Comment: [Is premature optimization really the root of all evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`String.Concat` is more efficient because it knows all the string lengths from the start. So it can allocate a single buffer with just the right length, copy the strings into it and return that buffer.

`StringBuilder` has to allocate a small buffer, reallocating and copying everytime a call to `Append` causes it to run out of space. The final call to `ToString()` also has to allocate yet another buffer.

So use `String.Concat` when you know in advance how many strings you have; use `StringBuilder` when you don't.

In C#, chained calls to the + operator are automatically converted to a single call to `String.Concat`.

Comment: And if you concatenate string *constants*, the *compiler* will already perform the concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Direct concatination needs less objects and memory calls. So it is faster, if you concatinate all strings (with out any text processing) in one statement.

In this case the compiler can calculate the size of the new string and allocate the memory and copy all chars into it. So you create only the object you want.

If you are using the StringBuilder, you use an additional object. If you append long strings without telling the StringBuilder in the constructor to use a huge buffer size, the string builder may do multiple memory allocations and copies, because it may run several times over the standard memory allocations.

StringBuild is the better solution, if you build your string in a loop. In this case the direct concatination will create a new object and memory allocation in each iteration, where StringBuild use only one memory allocation (if you use the right value in the constructor) and only two objects.

But it is hard to tell something about the runtime. The implementation changes over time. So what is now best practice may be worst practice in 5 years.